# ResourceDictionary Template reference to Self

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, resourcedictionary

I've got a CustomButton (let's call it MetroButton) which derives from Button and adds 3 properties: Size, ImageSource and Text. Size describes the Width and Height of the Control at the same time.

MetroButtons consists of a Template - now I want to carve-out the Template into a Stand-Alone ResourceDictionary.xaml - but how could I reference the Width and Height of the Button to the custom property "Size" ?

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border x:Name="_border"
                Width="{Binding Size,
                                ElementName=_metroButton,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                Mode=TwoWay}"
                Height="{Binding Size,
                                 ElementName=_metroButton,
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                 Mode=TwoWay}"
                Background="{StaticResource DefaultButtonBackgroundColor}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource DefaultButtonBorderColor}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
```

At the moment I'm able to use ElementName because the Template is defined directly inside the MetroButton class - if the Template is defined outside the class there is no chance to reference the ElementName (afaik) - and using

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}
```

won't lead to the expected result either - then the Styles won't apply at all.

Any solutions?

Comment: Why aren't you putting the template into the default theme xaml? The control template would then be targeting `MetroButton` type, and you can simply use `TemplateBinding`.

Comment: Omg, you're so right - as described I wanted to put the Template into the Default.xaml but I forgot that then I'm able to target MetroButton directly. If you take your comment and put it into an answer I'll set is as the solution :)

Comment: Okay, unfortunately It's not that easy - Idk why it worked at first glance. MetroButton is defined as a Button (<Button x:Class="[...]MetroButton"[...]>) so the TargetType of the Style and the Template has to be "Button" instead of MetroButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type yourButton}